# Manga where the main character attends a school because of memories of his previous life

Tags: story-identification, manga

The main character is serving a noble family and has to go to a prestigious school (only meant for nobles and the royal family). His mistress (master) breaks this news to him in the 4th chapter because he has memories from his previous life and all the people with memories of their previous lives have to go to this school. I think there are 4 chapters since I last saw, I am not sure if the 5th chapter has come out yet.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?  Was it online?

Comment: Hi and welcome! Please take a look at the [tour], [help], [ask] and [answer] to learn how to make more use of the stack exchange format. If you have any more details please [edit] them in after reading the guidance in [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info).

Comment: I read it in January and it was online

Comment: Did they determine that he had memories of his past life because he had a fever? Or did he just tell them?

Comment: @GSKOF - Another user with the username 'GSKOF' has attempted to edit this question. If that person is you, and you can no longer access the account you used to post this question, please merge your new account with your previous one by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). This will allow you to edit this question yourself, and mark a correct answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).